# percentage of progress bar does not work correctly(I'm interested in understanding the code forms)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The percentage of progress bar does not work correctly

The correct progress bar does not work and it's 100% fast

But the file has not uploaded yet

Click the submit button

The progress bar is completed quickly

But still the file is being uploaded

**I'm interested in understanding the code forms**

```
        <?php
            $msg = [
                 "title file"
                ,"url file"
                ,"send file"
            ];
        ?>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-rtl.css"  rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .del {
                border-radius: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 13px;
                height: auto;
                margin-right: 4px;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .box {
                height: 41px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            #uploadurl {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin-bottom: 7px;
                margin-top: 14px;
                padding-top: 11px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var template = '<div class="form-group box">' +
                '<input type="text" class="col-sm-5 form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="<?=$msg[0]?>">' +
                '<input type="text" class="col-sm-6 form-control" name="url[]" placeholder="<?=$msg[1]?>">' +
                '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger del"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
                '<div class="progress-bar progress progress-bar-success myprogress" role="progressbar" style="width:0%">0%</div></div>';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.add').on('click',function (e) {
                    $("#uploadurl").append(template);
                });
                $(document).on('click','.del',function (e) {
                    var del = $(this).closest('.box').index();
                    $('.box').eq(del).remove();
                });
                $('#submit').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("input[name='url[]']").each(function (index, value){
                        $('.myprogress').eq(index).css('width', '0');
                        var url = $(this).val();
                        var title = $("input[name='title[]']").eq(index).val();
                        if(title == ""){
                            title = <?=strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:s:i'))?>;
                        }else{
                            title =<?=strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:s:i'))?>+"_"+title;
                        }
                        var data = "url="+url+"&title="+title;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "upload.php",
                            data: data,
                            datatype:"json",
        //                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                            processData: false,
                            // this part is progress bar
                            xhr: function () {
                                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                                        $('.myprogress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                                        $('.myprogress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                                    }
                                }, false);
                                return xhr;
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#fileupload').append("<a style='display: block' href='"+data+"'>"+data+"</a>");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="upload-form" method="post">
                <div id="uploadurl" class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group box">
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-5 form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="<?=$msg[0]?>">
                        <input type="text" class="col-sm-6 form-control" name="url[]" placeholder="<?=$msg[1]?>">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success myprogress" role="progressbar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: block">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success add">+</a>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" id="submit" value="<?=$msg[2]?>" name="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="fileupload">

            </div>
        </div>
```

upload.php

```
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
        $url   =  $_POST['url'];
        $now = date('Y-m-d h:s:i');
        $partition = date('Ym', strtotime($now));
        $folder = "file/attach/".$partition."/";
        if (!file_exists($folder)) {
            $old = umask(0);
            mkdir($folder, 0777);
            umask($old);
        }
        $p = pathinfo($url);

        $newfile = $folder.$title.".".$p['extension'];

        if ( copy($url, $newfile) ) {
            echo $newfile;
        }else{
            echo "false";

        }
```

Click on the link below to view the demo

In the firebug you see, the file is still being uploaded

But the percentage of progress has been 100%.

[demo](http://jiraweb.ir/test2)

Comment: I'm interested in understanding the code forms

Comment: I noticed that the progress bar can not work for uploading the link, and that's completely logical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I needed a progress bar to add to my file downloads(in my project); I used this code. I have tested this code also. Try the code below; I am quite sure it will serve your purpose:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Progress Demo</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 
10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 
1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px;  
}
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
<code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile"></code>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
complete: function(xhr) {
 bar.width("100%");
percent.html("100%");
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
}
}); 

})();       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My php upload file:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
 } else{
echo "There was an error in the upload, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Hope it helps you and serve as a documentation for you...Happy coding

Comment: Thank you Mandy8055
But I'm interested in understanding the code forms

Comment: Fine!! I am quiet sure this video would help you get the better insight of it:                                                              https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-wXTpbNWoM

Comment: I noticed that the progress bar can not work for uploading the link, and that's completely logical

Comment: What does that suppose to mean?Your problem statement was problem regarding the working of progress bar regarding file. Isn't it?

Comment: The code you provided is correct.
But the problem with my code was that I uploaded the link, not files for the same progress bar, faster than uploading the file.
In fact, in the posting link, the progress bar does not work correctly and you must submit the form. And do not use ajax